# Android Studio / gradle: automated image resizing for android

Tags: android, image, gradle, android-studio

I'm using `Android Studio` with `Gradle`.

I wonder whether there is any way to automate image resizing for different resolutions at build time. I mean to have one set of the images and to resize automatically to various resolutions (e.g. `xxhdpi`, `xhdpi`, `hdpi`, `mdpi`, `ldpi`)

Perfect solution would be to have some gradle plugin which can be configured to produce resized images in appropriate folder before building `apk`

Comment: yes and no. Yes - with power of groovy you can call any command line tool or java library to resize images. No - I think image resizing shouldn't be part of build process, but can be an task in build script

Comment: Take a look to http://www.ainotenshi.org/818/resizing-images-using-the-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed a gradle plugin that allow doing exactly that (based on imagemagick)

First, you need to add the plugin to the build script :

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.eowise:gradle-imagemagick:0.4.0'
  }
}
```

Then, add a task for each size :

```
[
        [ variant: 'mdpi', size: '33%' ],
        [ variant: 'hdpi', size: '50%' ],
        [ variant: 'xhdpi', size: '66%' ],
        [ variant: 'xxhdpi', size: '100%' ]
].each {
    item ->
        task("buildIcons${item.variant.capitalize()}", type: com.eowise.imagemagick.tasks.Magick) {
            convert 'resources/images', { include '*.png' }
            into "app/src/main/res/drawable-${item.variant}"
            actions {
                -background('none')
                inputFile()
                -resize(item.size)
                outputFile()
            }
        }
}
```

You can find more informations about how to use this plugin on [the wiki page](https://github.com/eowise/gradle-imagemagick/wiki) on [GitHub](https://github.com/eowise/gradle-imagemagick).

Comment: Great! Looks exactly what I need! I suggest adding one more very useful feature: palette reduction in png, which allows improving compression ratio. Just like is done in tinypng (see http://tinypng.com)

Comment: @Aurel, pls help me. Tell me what I did wrong in my solution: http://pastebin.com/FypRBV9V